# Monotonic integral proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$ such that $f(x) \geq 0 $
for every $x\in [a,b]$. Suppose $\int_a^b f = 0$ and show that $f (x) = 0$ for every $x\in [a,b]$.
 obv this is monotonic ( non-decreasing definitionaly) i would liek to show monotonic non increaseing.

We know that $\int_a^b f = 0$ 
i have a theorem that says S(P) = s(P) = $\sigma$ over a Partition P on [a,b] or my integral does not exists.

So we have $(S(P) = \sigma) \leq 0$  is this enough to make a statement that my function is monotonic non increaseing?

if so how can we combine monotonic non-increase and monotonic non-decreasing to show that $f(x) = 0, \forall x \in [a,b]$?

EDIT:
my only other trick / idea i can come up with is that $\int_a^b |f| = 0$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f(x_1)=A>0$ for some $x\in [a,b]$. Then, by continuity, for $\varepsilon:=A/2$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $x\in (x_1-\delta,\,x_1+\delta) \,\implies\, |f(x)-f(x_1)|<\varepsilon$, which in this case implies $f(x)>A/2$.

As the interval $(x_1-\delta,\,x_1+\delta)$ intersects $[a,b]$ at least on a length of $\delta$, and as $f(x)\ge 0$ everywhere, we have
$$\int_a^bf\ge \frac{A\delta}2 \ >0\,.$$

Comment: I think you need to further assume that $\delta<b-a$ (or something like that) in order to conclude that $[a,b]\cap(x_1-\delta,x_1+\delta)$ has length at least $\delta$.

Comment: Well, yes. Choose $\delta$ the minimum of $\delta$ and $(b-a)/2$, say..